# Some Parts (HDRi, Water) of my animation render out white, but look perfectly fine in Material mode

Tags: rendering, hdri

I animated what is going to be the opening shot of a race, and I'm having a couple of issues. When I would do test renders, the render would look awesome, but somewhere along the line it got messed up and I don't know what happened.  The water that I created looks perfect in Material mode, as well as render mode, but when I render it officially, it is plain white. This is also the case for my HDRi.

Another quirky thing that is going on is when I officially render it, a part of a car shows up in the water, but it isn't there in the scene when I go back to try and delete it...
This is what it looks like when I render it:
[image]

I've put a lot of time into this and would greatly appreciate it if someone could help out.
Here is the file via Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3qRLZ0foPMIjY-tmJxcfzqEhHkDOfVg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You most certainly have hidden objects in viewport but not in rendering. Go to the sieve icon in the top right of your outliner and check the computer and the camera icons. Then if one of your object has the camera icon but not the computer icon, that means it will show in your renders but not in your viewport. You can also check that in the visibility foldout of the object properties

Comment: Well, another strange thing is, there are only eyes on the right of each object.  I don't know if I changed the settings or something, but there aren't the usual computer and camera icons.  Hmm...

Comment: You can enable the other icons by clicking on the sieve icon on the top right of your outliner. It will open a popup where you can check these icons

Comment: Click on the funnel icon at the top right of the outliner, then the different filters will be available for you to edit. Visible objects in the 3d vieport are controlled by the eye icon, renderability is cotrolled by the camera icon. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdvx2.png

Comment: Well, sure enough, the reason the HDRi wasn't coming through because there was a white mesh of some sort that went around the entire scene, covering up the HDRi.  Fixed!!  Thank you all so much. :D